# IntelliJ plugin JBoss jPBM plugin not working

Tags: intellij-idea, jbpm, bpmn

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition). I am trying to use JBoss jBPM plugin for BPMN designer. The designer tab is visible after installing the plugin, however when I navigate to the designer tab, a notification pops up: "generating Designer component" and after that Intellij just hangs and doesn't respond.

Expecting to see designer component

Comment: It seems to be a known problem. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286926 for more details